# Getting the correct appearance of colors in surface plots

Tags: graphics3d

```
ListPlot3D[
  Table[{i, jk, kk}, {kk, 1, 5}, {i, 1, 6}, {jk, 1, 6}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  Mesh -> All, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 
  FontSize -> 24, Black], 
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[.005], 
  AxesLabel -> {"[B] mol%", "[C] mol%", "E"}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1., 
  PlotStyle -> {Cyan, Pink, Green, Brown, Yellow}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
    SwatchLegend[
      Automatic, {4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 6.0, 6.5}, 
      LegendLabel -> HoldForm[Subscript[R, 0] (nm)], 
      LabelStyle -> {Helvetica, Bold, 24}]],
```

When plotting a set of surfaces with the above code, I do not get a graphic with the desired colors — cyan and pink don't look like cyan or pink and using `Hue` does not help either. Any suggestions?

Also how do I attach the graphics output/image so you can see what I am talking about?

Comment: Does `PlotStyle -> {{Cyan}, {Pink}, {Green}}` help? Your are more likely to get help if you post a simple working code.

Comment: Also `Helvetica` should be `FontFamily -> "Helvetica"`.

Comment: No, PlotStyle->{{Cyan},{Pink}} is not the solution. The issue had to do with lighting and the question was answered correctly by Lowriniak below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: Fix for font definition*

Try adding `Lighting -> "Neutral"` and changing the `PlotStyle` of each surface to have the `Specularity` to make the surface have less 'glare'.  Often the rendering of 3D graphics is modified by lighting, specularity and so on which will make colours look a little different.

The previous code gave:

[image: originalcolours]

And the modified code is:

```
ListPlot3D[
  Table[{i, jk, kk}, {kk, 1, 5}, {i, 1, 6}, {jk, 1, 6}],
  InterpolationOrder -> 3,
  Mesh -> All,
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontSize -> 24, Black],
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[.005],
  AxesLabel -> {"[B] mol%", "[C] mol%", "E"},
  PlotRange -> All,
  AspectRatio -> 1.,
  PlotStyle -> {
    {Specularity[White, 100], Cyan},
    {Specularity[White, 100], Pink},
    {Specularity[White, 100], Green},
    {Specularity[White, 100], Brown},
    {Specularity[White, 100], Yellow}
  },
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[
    Automatic, {4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 6.0, 6.5}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}
  ],
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

Resulting in this:

[image: colours]

This could probably still be tweaked, but these are the types of options you need to try.

Comment: `LabelStyle -> {"Helvetica", Bold, 24}` should be `LabelStyle -> {Bold, 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]`. It's hard to see the difference, but you can see it easily if you compare `LabelStyle -> {Bold, 24, "Times New Roman"}]` to  `LabelStyle -> {Bold, 24, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}]`.

Comment: Oh, sure.  I didn't test much of the other code but I will edit that in now.

Comment: Thanks lowriniak, for the information about Specularity and Lighting. It was most useful. Goldberg's comment that the issue I had was due to trivial syntax error is not true. The question I had was about appearance of color only and Lowriniak gave me the required information.

Comment: Setting Lighting->"Neutral" gives true colors, just using Specularity[White,100] did not change the appearance of the color.

Comment: The specularity does not change the colours themselves, it just stops them being obscured at certain rotations (because of reflection/glare)